# Address Book in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am now making an address book using js. This is an exercise from codecademy. I am now trying to write a function that lists all users. Here is what I have so far:

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}
```

This is the whats is killing me. The error I am getting is "SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'for'. I know it seems a little incomplete, but not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
var list = function () {
  var contactsLength = 
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++);
    printPerson();
}
list();
```

Comment: Look at the line before the `for` loop.

Comment: `var contactsLength =`
should be
`var contactsLength = contacts.length;`

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting - seems a great question to me. Plenty of code that has been tried and a good question. Well done and welcome. Ignore people that down-vote with no reason given..

Comment: I don't know who came up with the phone numbers, but they are real, as far as I could find out short of calling them. 650-777-7777 is the a taxi service (Yellow Cab) in Millbrae, CA 94030 and 650-888-8888 is-by pure coincidence?-the number of an Apple shop in Foster City, CA 94401. So, if you have chosen that numbers: please use the official ones for such usage in the USA: 555-01xx, just like you used example.com as a placeholder for an URL. The people holding these numbers might be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues. One of which has been pointed out (missing the assignment of the `contactsLength`; though you don't actually need to do this if you look at my second chunk of code.

The other is a little less obvious - you need to pass in a person to the `printPerson()` method. Your `printPerson()` method has a parameter `person`. This needs passing in.

So change your code to this:

```
var list = function () {
  var contactsLength = contacts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++)
    // You need to pass in the person to print!
    // contacts[i] is going to fetch the person in the list at position i
    printPerson(contacts[i]); 
}
list();
```

Also - the contactsLength isn't really needed. You can just call `contacts.length` in the loop instead (as you had before)

```
var list = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
    printPerson(contacts[i]); // You need to pass in the person to print!
}
list();
```

Comment: The trailing `;` after the `for` header is also incorrect.

Comment: Good call. Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactsLength =
```

That line is causing your syntax error.

I'm guessing you wanted:

```
var contactsLength = contacts.length;
for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    printPerson();
}
```

**Note** Your loop was also missing a closing bracket.

Comment: *"Your loop was also missing a closing bracket."* Actually no, because the `for` loop doesn't have an opening bracket. What's wrong is that the `for` loop is empty. Remove the `;` at the end of the line (and the `}`) and it will be fine.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh look at that. Updating.